# Centos 7: Filesystem type iso9660 not configured in kernel

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I installed the new kernel which fixed a mouse issue, but now I do not have full screen anymore. I am trying to get guest additions to work again but I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Were there any recent upgrades that may have upgraded the CentOS kernel ?

Comment: Maybe similar issue and solution like for Ubuntu here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/596998/unable-to-install-guest-additions-unknown-filesystem-type-iso9660 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your system is missing a kernel module needed to mount iso file system....the module is `isofs.ko` and it is dependent on module `nls_base.ko`.... you can check the dependency using `depmod`. Once you have verified the missing modules, insert them using `insmod`
[Check this link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/can%27t-mount-cd-unknown-filesystem-type-%27iso9660%27-766608/)